# Problem with rewrite

Tags: multistore

I have a multilanguage(many view) web site:

```
www.pincopallo.com
```

If i am into

```
www.pincopallo.com/it/rosso
```

and i click into switch language i should to go

```
www.pincopallo.com/en/red
```

(same category), but i go to

```
www.pincopallo.com/en/rosso
```

Is a bug? How i can resolve it? It's a problem rewrite module?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this be creating 301 redirects in the url management section.
For example, for the EN store you should create a redirect from `rosso` to `red`.
And for the IT store you should create a redirect from `red` to `rosso`.
This is a lot of work to do manually, that's why I recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/CmsRewrites).
This will give you a section in the backend where you enter the url keys for all of your languages and the redirects will be automatically created.
So you fill in the form like this:

```
IT: rosso
EN: red
FR: rouge
```

All of the redirects will be created automatically:

```
FOR IT:  red->rosso
FOR IT:  rouge->rosso
FOR EN:  rosso->red
FOR EN:  rouge->red
FOR FR:  rosso->rouge
FOR FR:  red->rouge
```